# ASP.NET Core 6 Web API: "The value string is not valid for DateTime."

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, multipartform-data

I am practicing passing value to a form in Angular, and then put it in a post url in ASP.NET Core.

Here is what I do - this is my component:

```
export class Demo11CreateDeleteApiComponent implements OnInit {
    form: FormGroup;
    file: any;

    constructor(
        private productApiService: ProductApiService,
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    ){}

    ngOnInit() { 
        this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
            name: '',
            price: 0,
            quantity: 0,
            status: true,
            description: '',
            photo: '',
            categoryId: 1
        })
        
    }

    fileControl(e:any){
        this.file = e.target.files[0];
    }

    submit(){      
        let product: ProductApi = this.form.value;
        
        //=======================
        //Assuming ProductApi is like this:
            ProductApi{
                name: string = "test";
                price: number = 1;
                quantity: number = 1;
                status: boolean = true;
                description: string = "test";
                created: string = "16/02/2023" the format is "dd/MM/yyyy";
                photo: string = "";
                categoryId: number = 1;
            }
        //=======================

        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('data', this.file);
        

        for (let k in product) {
            formData.append(`product.${k}`, product[k]);            
        }

        this.productApiService.createWithFile(formData).then(
            res => {
                this.result = do something;
            },
            err => {
                console.log(err);                
            }
        )
    }

}
```

And the `createWithFile` method looks like this:

```
async createWithFile(file: FormData){
    return await lastValueFrom(this.httpClient.post(this.baseUrl+'create-with-file', file));
}
```

Now in ASP.NET Core 6, my product class is:

```
public partial class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Invalid data, must be a non-empty string")]
    public string? Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Invalid data, must be an integer")]
    public int? Quantity { get; set; }

    public string? Description { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Invalid data, must be a double")]
    public double? Price { get; set; }    

    public bool Status { get; set; }    

    public string? Photo { get; set; }

    public DateTime Created { get; set; }  

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the controller:

```
[HttpPost("create-with-file")]
[Produces("application/json")]
public IActionResult CreateWithFile(Product product, IFormFile data)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
    catch
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
}
```

What I expect is, the product from ASP.NET Core will take all values from Angular with no problem, but instead, I get this error:

> product.Created: ["The value '16/02/2023' is not valid for Created."]

That means `ModelState` returned false because the `Created` method field. I look for many answers in SOF but no answer solved my problem, I even do this but it doesn't work either:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime Created { get; set; }
```

I've kinda reached a dead end, please help :(

Comment: Why are you using `(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}"` if submitted value is `dd/MM/yyyy`?

Comment: @Guru Stron  yes i am

Comment: In your Angular side, you should send the date format as `dd-MM-yyyy` instead of `dd/MM/yyyy` to match the format in the `DisplayFormat` attribute as GuruStron mentioned. A recommended approach is to send the date as [ISO 8601 format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString): "2023-02-16T00:00:00.000Z"

Comment: @YongShun my good sir, you did it again, you save me :), thank you again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you should pass the date as ISO 8601 format instead of "dd/MM/yyyy" so that the API side will receive the date correctly.

With [`Date.prototype.toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

```js
let now = new Date();

// To remove time from date
let created = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate()).toISOString();  
// 2023-02-16T16:00:00.000Z
product.created = created;
```

Note that the ISO String will be in the UTC offset.